# Get business details from SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, security

I recently got scammed by a site posing to belong to a legitimate company.

The business showed up on the HK exchange as being legitimate, and I checked several other sources for a legitimacy, and the business itself was legitimate. However, the site was not and was not linked to them. The SSL cert was letsencrypt, and of course there is no requirement to register a legitimate business with a letsencrypt cert, but even if the scammers had registered with setigo, they could use any business to register with setigo, it would not have to be reflected in the name of the domain, but if setigo make the business address, name etc publicly available in the SSL cert, then a visitor to a site could determine if the site legitimately represents the business. I am looking at another site now which has a setigo SSL cert, but I can't get any information about the business it is registered to from the certificate as presented by the browser.

Is there any way to get information of the business that registered the SSL certificate from the certificate itself?

Answer (score 6):

EV (extended validation) certificates have verified information about the business, but not the normal DV (domain validated) certificates. All what is required for these to get a certificate is to have control over the domain the certificate is issued for. So you might try [whois lookup](https://who.is/) for this domain to find out who registered it, but often these information are deliberately hidden by the domain registrar.

Apart from that a certificate should never be used to make assumptions about the security or trustworthiness of a site. The server certificate bound to a domain name is only to protect the HTTPS encryption by ensuring that the client actually connects to the domain name given in the URL and not to some man in the middle attacker intercepting access to the real domain.

Comment: BLUF: The use of a certificate has absolutely no standing of the company is legitimate or not, criminals often will and do create valid certificates, as part of their criminal enterprise. Let’s Encrypt is trusted by default by all browsers likewise, all it takes to create a Let’s Encrypt certificate, is control over the domain and the ability to routinely renew the certificate

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other information in the certificate file than what you already have.

However, this is very common, and the authorities that you report this to can serve the Internet Security Research Group (ISRG) with a subpoena for information that ISRG retains, such as the IP address and email address linked to the requestor. For more information:

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/trying-to-find-the-certificate-owner/100185/2

https://letsencrypt.org/documents/isrg-cps-v4.4/